# How can I monito Mic Level in my Electron app

Tags: node.js, typescript, electron

I need to find out the volume of the voice in the microphone, in my Electron application.

I tried to listen to the microphone through the node-mic library, and then find out the status of the microphone (silence, active), but this library does not want to work with Electron

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.